# ESLint object-shorthand error in Vue2 project, when I use @vue/reactivity-tranform macros and defineExpose()

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I use Vue3 Reactivity Transform macros and defineExpose() in Vue2 Project By [unplugin-vue2-script-setup](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue2-script-setup). I hope I can use eslint object-shorthand rules , but it was error when I use $$ and the key and value of property are same. What should I do to make ESLint not report error.

my code:

```
defineExpose({ myCode: $$(myCode) })
```

ESLint config:

```
rules: {
    'object-shorthand': ['error', 'always'],
},
```

I find that code will be transformed to `defineExpose({ myCode: (myCode) })` by reactivity-transform. The key `myCode` and  value `myCode` are the same. So it could have been simplified but it wasn't.  ESLint  object-shorthand will throw error.

In ESLint object-shorthand source code, it uses AST Node property `shorthand`, if the key and value are same ,and the value of `shorthand` is `false`,it will throw error. Maybe , if the compiler result of reactivity-transform is simplified , the ESLint object-shorthand rules will not error ?

Comment: I doubt that something can be done without fixing these tools. unplugin and reactivity transform introduce too much magic, this is a consequence IMO. Try to just disable linter rule for this line if you wish to stick to this kind of style